# Snowflake:To append the count of rows to the tail end of the file while unloading into S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: To append the count of rows to the tail end of the file

**SQL**

```sql
COPY INTO @s3bucket/path/filename.txt
FROM(SELECT
        a.acct_num,
        a.state,
        CASE WHEN b.tn IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END IND
     FROM table_A a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table_B b ON a.tn = b.tn
    );
```

**Expected output** `TR|3` should be appended to tail end of the file

```
"1111"|"NEWYORK"|"N"
"2222"|"NEWJERSEY|"Y"
"333"|"TEXAS"|"N"
TR|3
```

> **EDIT 1:**

Uploaded the data using the COPY command as mentioned by  @Iron DBA
And Implemented the Python function to update the tailing row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use UNION ALL to include the count as the last line:

```
copy into @deneme from 
(
with st as (
select * from values 
('1111','NEWYORK','N'),
('2222','NEWJERSEY','Y'),
('333','TEXAS','N') tmp(acct_num, state, ind ) ) 
  select acct_num, state, ind from (
  select *, 0 sorting_column from st
  union all
  select 'TR',count(*)::VARCHAR,null, 1 from st)
  order by sorting_column
);

select $1, $2, $3 from @testing;


+------+-----------+----+
| $1   | $2        | $3 |
+------+-----------+----+
| 1111 | NEWYORK   | N  |
| 2222 | NEWJERSEY | Y  |
| 333  | TEXAS     | N  |
| TR   | 3         |    |
+------+-----------+----+
```

Comment: Have tried the same as your query as above, the issue is TR|3 should be at the last row and there should be not extra pipe , as it will be like `"TR"|"3"|`

Comment: It's not possible to remove the extra pipe. To be sure that the TR comes as last row, I just modified the query and added a sorting column.

Comment: ok, also I am trying to save as `filename.txt`, it is saving a CSV format ... Does Snowflake have txt format

Comment: Have you tried to set FILE_EXTENSION?https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#syntax

Comment: Got it working... Now thinking about how to eliminate the extra pipe in the last row...Maybe python should help in eliminating only for the last row